# MediaPlayer cant play audio files from program data folder?

Tags: android

When i record my audio from MIC and store file in /data/data/..... why 
MediaPlayer can't play this file ? If i change destination to / 
sdcard/..... - all works great. I do something wrong ? I not found 
limitation for MediaPlayer.  Device - Samsung T959 (Galaxy S) 
Thanks, i hope anybody know solution....

Comment: I am facing the same issue, have you found some solution?

Answer (score 7):

i had the same issues... whenever i used setDataSource with filepaths, it would not work; kept getting IOException.

changing my code to use setDataSource(FileDescriptor) does work... and with this i don't have to copy the files to SDCard or anything like that.

So, with a simple File object, create a new FileInputStream and pass the actual file descriptor as data source as in:

```
setDataSource((new FileInputStream(myFileInstance)).getFD());
```

creating an input stream pulls the file data into memory and thereby addresses /data/data access violations.

Comment: This example doesn't dispose of the input stream like https://stackoverflow.com/a/19081490/309644

Answer (score 3):

Better practice is to close the stream, like this:

```
FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(path);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(stream.getFD());
stream.close();
```

Even better from Kotlin:

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(
  FileInputStream(path).use { it.fd }
)
```

It is noted in the documentation of the method:

[`android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(FileDescriptor fd)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource(java.io.FileDescriptor))

> Sets the data source (`FileDescriptor`) to use. It is the caller's
> responsibility to **close** the file descriptor. It is safe to do so **as
> soon as this call returns**.

Answer (score 1):

use MediaPlayer.setDataSource(FileDescriptor fd)

Comment: I had the same problem where the recorded file in /data/data/your package/files/myfile.3gp was not playing with mediaplayer. Setting the filedescriptor helped in sorting that out.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting ContentValues and to store some standard meta-data properties. Then using a ContentResolver to set the meta-data and Uri to the file.

see: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html

"Example: Audio Capture Setup and Start", then try changing `Uri base` to your /data/data/-filename.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but changing Uri base not working :( Illegal argument exception appers when inserts to base

Answer (score 0):

Due to the Android security model, MediaPlayer haven't enough rights. It can access SD card, but can't access another places with out permissions.

As so, setDataSource(...) can thrown SecurityException and I think it's happening.

### You can play this file next ways:

- copy it to temp dir and play;
- copy it to temp dir and play;
- copy it to sdcard;
- read it fully to memory and try play via stream.