# MediaRecorder records bad audio file on Droid X2

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-mediarecorder

I'm trying to record audio using MediaRecorder on the Droid X2, and I'm running into issues. The MediaRecorder seems to prepare and start recording just fine, but when I stop recording and try to listen to the file that is produced the playback immediately stops. Even if I try to open the audio file in the standard media player app, it immediately stops.

Here's the code I'm using to record:

```
mCurrentRecordingFilePath = mContext.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + fileName;

mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
mRecorder.setOutputFile(mCurrentRecordingFilePath);
mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
// mRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(16);
// mRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);

try {
    mRecorder.prepare();
    mIsPrepared = true;
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("Test", "MediaRecorder prepare() failed");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
if (mRecorder != null && mIsPrepared) {
    mRecorder.start();
    mIsRecording = true;
    Log.i("Test", "Started audio capture: " + mCurrentRecordingFilePath);
}
```

I commented out the `setAudioEncodingBitRate()` call because it was causing the `prepare()` to fail, and just to be on the safe side I also commented out `setAudioSamplingRate()`. I have tried every combination of output format and audio encoder that is available and the result is always the same. I get no exceptions, and a file is created that is not empty, but it will not play back properly.

Not sure if it will help diagnose, but here's the code I use to stop recording:

```
if (mRecorder != null && mIsRecording) {
    mRecorder.stop();
    mRecorder.release();
    mRecorder = null;
    mIsPrepared = false;
    mIsRecording = false;
    Log.i("Test", "Stopped audio capture");
}
```

The recording code works fine on a Galaxy Nexus, Nexus S, EVO 4G, and Galaxy SII. Any idea why my audio file would be bad on the Droid X2?

Comment: What if you specify `OutputFormat.THREE_GPP`, `AudioEncoder.AMR_NB`, one channel, 8000 Hz? Does that still fail? Can you play the resulting file (recorded by the Droid X2) on any of the other phones you mentioned?

Comment: I was able to play the file on my Mac using `OutputFormat.THREE_GPP` and `AudioEncoder.AMR_NB`. I also found that I'm able to play the file on the X2 if I set the path to the root of the SD card rather than the external files directory. I really want to avoid writing outside the files directory though since I want the audio files to be removed when the app is uninstalled.

Comment: Found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773262/mediaplayer-cant-play-audio-files-from-program-data-folder

Problem wasn't the recording, it was the way I was setting the MediaPlayer's datasource. Though I have no idea why the stock media player app wouldn't play the file... maybe it's a permission thing. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here: [MediaPlayer cant play audio files from program data folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773262/mediaplayer-cant-play-audio-files-from-program-data-folder)

Problem wasn't the recording, it was the way I was setting the MediaPlayer's datasource. Though I have no idea why the stock media player app wouldn't play the file... maybe it's a permission thing. Here's the code I was using to play the file:

```
mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mPlayer.setDataSource(fileName);
mPlayer.prepare();
mPlayer.start();
```

Here's the code that will work if the file is stored in the external files directory:

```
mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mPlayer.setDataSource((new FileInputStream(fileName)).getFD());
mPlayer.prepare();
mPlayer.start();
```